# File Sharing Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 & OSX Mavericks

Tags: networking, samba, mac, macbook

Trying to set up file share between Ubuntu Desktop & OSX Mavericks - have had massive issues so far due to my naivete. The Ubuntu Desktop machine will act as a server to a Macbook Pro & Raspberry Pi. Configuration for the Pi has been straightforward.

Here are the specs for each system:

**Ubuntu Machine**

- Ubuntu Desktop OS
- 2 Drives OS (128GB San Disk SSD) & Storage (2TB Seagate HDD)
- SSD is automatically partitioned as /dev/sda1 (fat32 512mb), sda2 (ext4 115gb) and /sda3 (unknown 3.8gb)
- HDD is partitioned as fat23 with 1.82TB

**Macbook Pro**

- OSX Mavericks (10.9.4)
- 500GB Internal HDD running Mac OS Extended (Journaled) file format

Q1) What is the recommended formatting for the Ubuntu HDD & the Mac? 
I've attempted to format the Seagate HDD to hfs+ to work with the Mac, but Gparted formatting editor has continually came back as failed.

Q2) What would be the best file sharing protocol for Ubuntu 14.04 & OSX Mavericks? I.e. AFP, SMB, FTP?

Comment: The question seems too broad. Please ask one question at a time and try to be as specific as possible in  what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar setup with Linux Mint & Mavericks and also went through your pain.

1st thing to check is that both machines can ping each other. 
Try

`-$ ping -c3 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

It might be helpful if you assign static IP's as well. Also, verify that SMB is the active share transport on the Mac (System Prefs/Sharing/options). AFP should not be necessary on the Mac. Still in preferences on the Mac, check file share permissions for the specific folders shared. You may need to create a user account on the Mac for your Linux users login.